# About Autodesk platform services, the 5 GB storage what does it means?

Tags: service, autodesk-forge, autodesk, platform

The free version of Autodesk platform services mention that 5 GB storage free. Does this storage include BIM models, or is it just for code?

Answer (score 0):

The 5GB applies for files stored in OSS buckets, so yes, BIM models. We only store binaries for Design Automation AppBundle.